# commands to move jenkins job from one view to another view using cURL

Tags: curl, jenkins, build, move, jobs

I wanted to move my existing Jenkins job from one jenkins view to another view.

While creating a new jenkins job we can mention the view in the URL and that works for me. But moving the job i couldn't get any clue for this.

Example: https:///view//createItem?name=

Can someone help or suggest ideas for the same, it would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You must have admin access to jenkins. Try following steps to move jenkins job from one view to another view.

1. Click on jenkins view from where you want to move to other view
2. Click on "Edit view" options at left side.
3. It will display list of jobs under "Job filters"
4. Select the checkbox which jobs you want to see in current view and if you want to move other view then uncheck checkbox.
5. Click on apply and OK to save changes
6. Now you will see desired jobs are displyed in current view. same procedure follow for other views so that you can easily move jenkins job from one view to another view.

Comment: Thanks for the response Shital. What i need is i want to move a Job from one view to another using commands, as i am automating a process. So can i get an input for that ?

Comment: I am using cURL to create new jenkins job automatically, it is creating in a particular view and i wanted to move the job to another after creation of jenkins job.